# Struct for binary tree (self referencing stucts)

Tags: struct, binary-tree, d

How should I constructs a self-referencing struct? E.g. a binary tree?
I assumed I should do it like below, but it throws `Segmentation fault: 11`

```
import std.typecons;

struct Node {
    int value;
    NullableRef!Node left, right;
}

void main() {
    Node n;
}
```

Comment: This is a compiler bug. Bisecting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I constructs a self-referencing struct? E.g. a binary tree? I assumed I should do it like below, but it throws `Segmentation fault: 11`

A segmentation fault during compilation indicates a compiler bug. In this case, it looks like it's a regression introduced in 2.068. I'll bisect and report it, so it should be fixed in the next release. Until then, you can downgrade to DMD 2.067 or earlier, which does not exhibit this bug.

If usage of `NullableRef` is not imperative, you can simply use plain pointers for now:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* left, right;
}

void main() {
    Node n;
}
```